# What happens when an ofstream object.open() is commented out?

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    ofstream out;
    ifstream in;

    out.open("The Necessary Death of Charlie Countryman2.srt");
        if (out.fail()) {
            perror("The Necessary Death of Charlie Countryman2.srt");
        }

    in.open("The Necessary Death of Charlie Countryman.srt");
        if (in.fail()) {
            perror("The Necessary Death of Charlie Countryman.srt");
        }

    vector<string> input;
    string inc;

    while (getline(in, inc)) {
        input.push_back(inc);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
        out << input[k] << endl;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

When I read from **somefile.txt** using ***ifstream* in** and write into **anotherfile.txt** using ***ofstream* in**, everything works fine, but suppose I comment out `out.open("anotherfile.txt")` and execute the code, there is no error and when I open **anotherfile.txt** it is empty.

My question is during

```
for (int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
            out << input[k] << endl;
        }
```

what happens?

Where or to what is `input[k]` sent to? If it was *cout* it goes to command prompt and if `out.open("anotherfile.txt")` was not commented then it goes to anotherfile.txt.

Comment: seems like it is sent to a buffer which is never used. But I couldn't find more info about it

Comment: When an output file isn't being opened, the text is simply loaded in a buffer and destroyed therein when the program terminates. Unless you open a file for reading, text you attempt to send to the output file will be relayed back to the stack.

Comment: @I3ck and @ Poriferous thank you both, this is what I wanted to know where does my `input[k]` is sent to.

Answer (score 2):

Every `<<` operation fails, and that's it (that's <sup>(1)</sup>all that happens).

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> A stream can be set in a mode where it throws exceptions on failures, but that's not the default. By default failures are just silently ignored. Except that the fail state bits are set, which you can check with either `fail()` or via conversion to `bool`.</sup>

Comment: I dont think `getline` fails, because `getline(in, inc)` reads from `in` which is `ifstream` object it has nothing to do with `out` which is `ofstream` object.

Comment: @nSv23: Oh, right you are: it's the other stream that's outcommented. Okay, fixing.

Comment: yes `input` is a `std::vector`, but this is pretty much the entire code, just read from `in` and write to `out`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `out` is declared to be an `ostream` (or a subclass such as `ofstream`). When you comment out the line `out.open(...)`, `out` is initialized as a closed file. As such when you try to write to it, nothing happens, and the injection fails... but **you** fail to test whether it succeeded or not!

If you tested it with:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < input.size(); k++) {
        out << input[k] << endl;
        if out.fail() {
            // process error condition...
        }
    }
```

you would pass in the error condition branch and would be able to know that the injection did not occur.

Answer (score 2):

`ofstream` uses this `operator<<` signature

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb);
```

From [cpppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), `operator<<`, 8)

> After constructing and checking the sentry object, checks if sb is a null pointer. If it is, executes setstate(badbit) and exits.

You can check this easily by doing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream sink;
    //sink.open("/dev/null");

    sink << "check state";

    switch(sink.rdstate())
    {
        case std::ios_base::failbit:
            std::cout << "stream state is failbit\n";
            break;
        case std::ios_base::goodbit:
            std::cout << "stream state is goodbit\n";
            break;
        case std::ios_base::eofbit:
            std::cout << "stream state is eofbit\n";
            break;
        case std::ios_base::badbit:
            std::cout << "stream state is badbit\n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3be93c8ae4ef9e1e): stream state is badbit

Answer (score 1):

`out` is an object of type `std::ostream`, similarly `std::cout` is an object of type `std::ostream` that lives in the global namespace (it is available in the beginning of your program).

objects of type `std::ostream` (output streams, including sub classes that extend it like `std::ofstream` ) have their `<<` operator overloaded.

this way having `cout<<"hello";` is the same thing as `std::cout.operator<<("Hello World");`

note that the overloaded `<<` operator returns a reference to the `ostream` object so `cout<<"hi" << " there";` is basically

```
std::cout.operator<<("hi").operator<<(" there"));
```

you need to open any output file stream before writing to it. By doing so, you are invoking a syscall to the OS that gives you access to the files so you can write to them. Otherwise, you are attempting to write to a closed file that your process has no access writing to.

you don't have to do this explicitly for `std::cout` but you should open your own output file streams.

Don't forget to close your open files!!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, he is asking why he needs to open the output stream before writing to it, and is wondering why cout behaves differently.

Comment: He or she asks what happens when writing to a stream which is *not* open.  The OP does not ask "how to write to a file?".